# React.js react-router-dom@6: Clicking Link element changes the url but not renders components

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, react-router-dom

Hello I am currently struggling with 'react-router-dom' @6 Link element.
Clicking the signup text belongs to the Link elements allows the browser url becomes
localhost:5000   ->   localhost:5000/signup
but still Signup component doesn't appear.
I have no idea where to correct my code.

```
import Form from './components/form';
import Comments from './components/comments';
import Header from './components/header';
import Signup from './components/signup';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './styles/app.scss';

function App() {
    const [ text, stateText ] = useState('');
    const [ user, stateUser ] = useState({});

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Header />
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/comments" element={<Comments text={text} />} />
                    <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
                    <Route
                        path="/"
                        element={<Form text={text} stateText={stateText} user={user} stateUser={stateUser} />}
                    />
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

the below one is header.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Router, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <div className="header_component">
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Link to="/signup">Signup</Link>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

lastly, the one which is below is index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import Header from './components/header';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
reportWebVitals();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links in the `Header` and the routes all need to be rendered within the ***same*** router. You only need one router per app to provide the routing context to all `Link`, `Routes`, `Route`, `Navigate`, `Outlet` components, and all RRD hooks.

Move `Header` into the `Router` in `App` and remove the `Router` in the `Header` component.

```
function App() {
  const [ text, stateText ] = useState('');
  const [ user, stateUser ] = useState({});

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/comments" element={<Comments text={text} />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={<Form text={text} stateText={stateText} user={user} stateUser={stateUser} />}
          />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

...

```
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className="header_component">
      <Link to="/signup">Signup</Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```